# Update и открытые методы

Tags: c#, unity3d

Может кто-то объяснить, можно ли делать так:

```
void Update() {
    GameObject1.SetActive(IsActive);
    GameObject2.SetActive(IsActive);
    GameObject3.SetActive(IsActive);
}
```

Скрипт весит на отдельном объекте, который никогда не скрывается.
В зависимости от `IsActive = true | false` элемент будет скрываться или показываться.
Или придется городить всякие флаги и условия?

Вида:

```
if(!IsActive1) {
   IsActive1 = true;
   GameObject1.SetActive(IsActive);
}
```

Не будет ли постоянный вызов `SetActive()` для нескольких объектов в методе `Update()` пагубно сказываться на производительности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoBehaviour методы вызываются только у скриптов, которые висят на "активных" (включенных GameObject). То есть когда вы сделаете объекту `GameObject.SetActive(false)`, то метод `Update()` у него не будет вызываться. Об этом можно почитать в документации по [GameObject.SetActive()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html).

Кроме того, если в иерархии объектов ваш GameObject не будет верхним (то есть у него будет какой-то родительский объект), то если вы сделаете родительский объект `SetActive(false)`, то и все дочерние элементы также будут неактивными. Соответственно и `Update()` у дочерних классов тоже не будет вызываться.

Сам по себе вызов `SetActive()` может быть дешевой операцией, если вы вызываете его для небольшого количества объектов (например для 3 как в вашей ситуации) и эти объекты просты с точки зрения иерархии (не содержат большой вложенности). Если же вы вызываете этот метод для большого числа и эти объекты сложные в плане вложенности, то это может оказать существенное влияние на производительность.

В целом, все очень сильно зависит от ситуации, так что пробуйте и профилируйте.

Comment: Стоп, вы видимо не правильно поняли или я вас. Есть к примеру один объект на который я вешаю скрипт, он всегда активный и в нем уже я делаю эти все `SetActiv'ы`, других объектов. И в зависимости от `IsActive` показываю или скрываю.

Comment: @Vendor В том виде, в котором вы изменили вопрос - в нем вообще нет смысла. Становится в целом не понятно, в чем вопрос, а ответ на него - попробуйте и узнаете, никаких дополнительных знаний тут не нужно

Comment: Что именно не понятно? Объект к которому привязан скрипт он никогда не выключается, а в методе его `Update` проверяется включены ли объекты? Что тут может быть не понятного? Данный объект может передвигаться и в зависимости от дистанции рядом появляются или скрываются объекты если дистанция не соответствует действительности. Сделать метод "АЛЯ ВЫЗЫВАТЬ 1 РАЗ КОГДА НУЖНО" не получится. Вот и в этом вопрос нормально ли постоянно в апдейте юзать SetActive и влияет ли как-то это на производительность?

Comment: @Vendor при этом в самом вопросе ни слова про производительность) Ответ на вопрос при этом не сильно изменится - пробуйте и профилируйте. Сама по себе операция может быть дешевой в зависимости от количества объектов, которые вы выключаете и их сложности в плане вложенности и иерархии объектов и дорогой (если на сцене очень сложные объекты с большой вложенностью и каждый кадр вы работаете с десятками или сотнями таких объектов. Все зависит исключительно от вашей ситуации

Comment: Теперь понятно, у меня всего таких 3 объекта - это кнопки, вложенность у них отсутствует.